# how to used paypal lib in non us developer

Tags: paypal, credit-card

Accept PayPal and allow direct credit card processing Non U.S. developers, please note that direct credit card processing is not offered to you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.

What I understand of this is that a Non U.S. account could no process Direct Credicard payments, but they don't say anything about others payment capabilities.

So I made my application, use the REST API in Sandbox and everything works great.

No I was setting the live application and I couldn't. After reading again the Documentation I found this:

Do I need a U.S. PayPal account to sign up? To accept payments using the new REST APIs and PayPal Mobile SDK, we currently require a U.S. PayPal Business account. But stay tuned for more country support. Note that most countries can use our Classic APIs.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Non-US accounts can accepts PayPal payments via both the REST API's as well as the mobile SDK. Processing card payments via REST and the mobile SDK is restricted to US, UK & CA.

Comment: Any update on Paypal Mobile SDK in non-US business accounts?

Comment: No still not update..